# How to execute parent function from child in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I need to execute the parent function from child which is imported. Child component is my button view. Please help to find a solution
in parent file:

```
export default function Home(props) {
    function test(){
        alert("asd")
    }

 <CardheaderSlider name="All" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="English" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="Mathematics" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="Science" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="Languages" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="Activity Books" />
                        <CardheaderSlider name="E-Training" />
}
```

CardheaderSlider file

```
export default class CardheaderSlider extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Pressable style={styles.button}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{this.props.name}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `onPress` attribute on your child:

```
export default class CardheaderSlider extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Pressable style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.onPress()}>
                <Text style={{ color: "#fff", fontWeight: "bold" }}>{this.props.name}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        )
    }
```

And call it like:

```
<CardheaderSlider name="All" onPress={() => myFunction()}/>
```